# Probability that the measurement will give +1 as a result for entangled state

Tags: entanglement

On page 28 of [this paper](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Elandsman/Sven2019.pdf) the following calculation is made:
$$P\left(\sigma_{\theta}=+1\right)=\left|\left\langle+\mid \Psi_{0}\right\rangle\right|^{2}=\cos ^{2} \frac{\theta}{2}$$

Can someone help me with the full calculation?

I wanted to know, how, using \begin{equation}
|+\rangle=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\cos \frac{\theta}{2} \\
\sin \frac{\theta}{2}
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

they made the calculation? What are the formulae I have to use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Quantum Stackexchange. Please clarify where in the derivation you have a problem understanding. If it is in the first equality, there is maybe a concept you haven't understood, whereas the second equality is only a vector calculation.